# Global variable value is not changing?

Tags: c++, global-variables

I have a program.

```
   int i=10;
   main()
   {
         extern int i;
         {
                int i=20;
                {
                     const volatile unsigned i=30;
                     printf("%d ",i);
                }
                printf("%d ",i);
          }
          printf("%d\n",i);
   }
```

output:   `30 20 10`

When I saw this program, I thought this program will gives an error. Because, we can't create a symbol(variable) with same name. Even we are creating symbol under blocks, already it is created as global symbol.

How can compiler differentiate global symbols and local symbols with same name?

Comment: `. Because, we can't create a symbol(variable) with same name.` why do you say that? Are you just guessing?

Comment: One word: scope.

Comment: Here's a good overview of C's scope rules: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-rules-in-c/

Comment: Why did you remove both language tags from this question?

Comment: @JohnDibling these are reasons.
1. I asked a stupid question.
2. I got the answers.
3. I'm getting down votes too.
4. I'm unable to delete

Comment: On StackOverflow, there are no stupid questions.  Only poorly-asked questions, poorly-researched questions, and off-topic questions.  Removing tags specifically to limit the visibility of the question and thereby mitigate downvotes is gaming the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing this with the One Definition rule, which states basically that in a single translation unit a single object can't have more (or less) than one definition.

But that's not what you're doing here.  What you're doing is creating two objects that just so happen to have the same name.  That is allowed and well-defined by the language, if not a great idea.

```
int i=10;
   main()
   {
         {
                int i=20;
                {
                     const volatile unsigned i=30;
                }
          }
   }
```

In this code you first define `i` as a global.  You then define a new variable also named `i` within a block scope.  Within that block scope, the locally-defined `i` *hides* the definition of the globally-defined one.  You can still refer to the globally-defined one via `::i`.

You then define yet another variable also named `i` in a deeper block.  This one also hides the previous two variables with the same name.

Don't write code like this.

Comment: "(or less)" - Not sure I quite agree with that bit - I'm sure I've seen projects where certain objects that are present in one translation unit have less than one definition in a different translation unit (i.e. they're not available at all in that unit).

Comment: @twalberg:  If an object isn't in a particular TU at all, then the ODR doesn't apply.  The ODR refers to objects within a TU.  If something is in a TU, it must have exactly one definition.

Answer (score 1):

> Because, we can't create a symbol(variable) with same name.

We can declare variables with same name in different scope.

> How can compiler differentiate global symbols and local symbols with same name?

When a declaration inside a block names an identifier that's **already visible** (*because it has file scope or because it's declared in an enclosing block*), the new declaration *temporarily hides* the old one, and the identifier takes on a new meaning. At the end of the block, identifier regains its old meaning.

Answer (score 1):

> Because, we can't create a symbol(variable) with same name.

Yes we can, as long as they're not both in the same scope. If, as here, one is in a nested scope, then it hides the declaration in the outer scope.

> How can compiler differentiate global symbols and local symbols with same name?

By looking first in the scope of the current block, then of the block containing that, and so on until either it finds a declaration or fails to find one in the global namespace. (In C++, things are a bit more complicated due to class scopes and namespaces; but the general principle is the same).

Answer (score 0):

I think that the compiler builds a tree of enclosed namespaces and blocks and starts to search unqualified names at the given level of the tree towards its root.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler always uses the declaration from the innermost enclosing "scope" (which really means "block").

Once you have declared a new one, the outer ones are inaccessible (unless you took a pointer).

Answer (score 0):

A variable inside a block has its own scope i.e whatever it does remains inside that block
and hence if we create another variable(with the same name) outside the block it would have its own scope

Answer (score 0):

> Because, we can't create a symbol(variable) with same name.

Your inner variable is local and it has higher priority then global variables. You can have both global and local, but while in block there is local variable using.